# How to override default behavior of mule SFTP endpoint?

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-component

I need to override the default behavior of the mule SFTP inbound endpoint. I have mule flow to pick files from SFTP location & do some alternation & send to a third party service. I don't have controller in file upload. So there may be number of files in same time.

I need to implement throttling mechanism there. For ex.: Mule flow need to pick the oldest 10 files with in one poll. So I'm planning to override default behavior of the mule SFTP client to achieve this. I'm using JAVA.

Comment: Do you want to use SFTP or FTP connector? These are different things (please edit your answer to precise which)

Comment: sorry mistakenly added FTP.  I need SFTP connector. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage [Transport Service Override](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-a-transport#service-overrides): implement your own [`SftpMessageReceiver`](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.8.0/transports/sftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpMessageReceiver.java) and configure your SFTP Connector to use this custom component such as:

```
<sftp:connector name="sftp-connector" ... />
    ...
    <service-overrides messageReceiver="com.mycomp.MySftpMessageReceiver" />
</sftp:connector>
```

I would recommend you override the [`poll()`](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/4afebcb3312f72de86bd0adae763d5e6f1510b11/transports/sftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpMessageReceiver.java#L71) function of the existing receiver for the Mule version you are using. For Mule 3.9 it will retrieve all files and call [`routeFile()`](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/4afebcb3312f72de86bd0adae763d5e6f1510b11/transports/sftp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/sftp/SftpMessageReceiver.java#L123) for each found files. You can implement your own `poll()` which will instead pick the 10 most recent files and reproduce the same behavior. I won't provide complete code sample here, but you can take inspiration of the existing function (retrieve, lock, route) to implement your own. For example:

```
public class MySftpMessageReceiver extends SftpMessageReceiver {
    ...
    @Override
    public void poll() throws Exception {
        //poll 10 oldest files
        //...
        //route them
        for (String file : files){
            //...
            routeFile(file);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Note overriding the existing `SftpMessageReceiver` is simply a way to go among others. The idea is to implement your own `MessageReceiver` and use the service overrides as stated above.

EDIT: as per @NNishanthi Wickramasinghe request to retrieve the private `SftpReceiverRequesterUtil`: you can create your own instance or retrieve the one created by the super constructor.

Looking at the code, you can see it's created with protected `createSftpReceiverRequesterUtil()` function and affected to a private field by the constructor. You can call this function in your own constructor do duplicate this behavior, or to avoid duplication override this method to retrieve the instanciated object and affect it to your own field, such as:

```
private SftpReceiverRequesterUtil sftpRRUtil = null;
...
@Override
protected SftpReceiverRequesterUtil createSftpReceiverRequesterUtil(InboundEndpoint endpoint) {
    sftpRRUtil = super.createSftpReceiverRequesterUtil(endpoint);
    return sftpRRUtil;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre for your response. I'm using mule 3.8. I tried to override the poll method in SftpMessageReceiver in my own class. with in poll() method its used  SftpReceiverRequesterUtil class to retrieve the files & LockFactory interface to lock files. But those are private variables & not visible in sub class. How do I mange this ?

Comment: You can create your own or even better, re-use the one created by the super constructor. Looking a the source code you can see the function used is protected and can be overriden, you can then us this to retrieve the instance and affect it to your own field. I'll edit with an example.